Unity Input Actions Enabled But Not Triggering
I was trying to implement Key Rebinding in Unity, and I was using the "new" input system, but I was also using the generated C# class, which I found by posts and videos that the best approach to key remaping is to use a PlayerController instead of the Generated Class.
So I deleted the GameControls generated script and adapted my InputManager (a class I created to handle inputs), so that it would could work according to some tutorials and posts.
Now none of my inputs are being registered, and I checked every post and video I found and tried to find a solution. I press the keys assigned to the InputActions, but nothing happenes, but when I used the generated C# class everything used to work with this setup.
Here is my InputManager GameObject
Here is a small part of the code for the InputManager class:
public class InputManager : TrueSingleton<InputManager>
{
    public InputAction Movement { get; private set; } = null;
    public InputAction LookDirection { get; private set; } = null;
    public InputAction DodgeRoll { get; private set; } = null;
    public InputAction Run { get; private set; } = null;
    public InputAction Aim { get; private set; } = null;
    ...

    PlayerInput playerInput;

    protected override void LoadDependencies()
    {
        playerInput = GetComponent<PlayerInput>();
        SetUpGameControls();
    }

    void SetUpGameControls()
    {
        Movement = playerInput.actions["Movement"];
        LookDirection = playerInput.actions["LookDirection"];
        DodgeRoll = playerInput.actions["DodgeRoll"];
        Run = playerInput.actions["Run"];
        Aim = playerInput.actions["Aim"];
        ...
    }
}

I also ensure that the action maps are enabled using this function:
public void ToggleActionMap(string actionMapName, bool newEnabled){
    if(newEnabled)
        playerInput.actions.FindActionMap(actionMapName).Enable();
    else
        playerInput.actions.FindActionMap(actionMapName).Disable();
}

The way I try to use this in outside scripts is like the following line:
if ((InputManager.Instance.Cancel.triggered || InputManager.Instance.ToggleInventory.triggered) ||...)
Here is the Game Controls scheme with the maps
While checking the InputDebug window there is only one User present with all the expected actions:
InputDebug window
I also checked via code debbuger if the actions where enabled, and also checked if their actions maps where enabled, but they were all according to what was expected:
Debugging Variable Results
I tried many things, using unity events by adding events in the PlayerInput class, I tried restarting the pc, since another tread having very similar problems to mine seem to have been the issue.
I alredy tried to see if the ProjectSettings/Player/Active Input Handling option was not enabled to Both, but it was.
The all InputActions and ActionMaps seem to be enabled
I just want to make this work to get the InputActions to trigger again.
I probably messed up somewhere, but I can't find where and I am in need of an outside view/help. I litteraly don't know what to do. Any suggestions are welcome and thanks in advance for your help!

This looks a little overcomplicated, have you followed a tutorial on how to use the new input system? Assining each action like this isn't needed if you let the map generate a c# class for you.

Is there a realiable way to use the C# generated script so I can rebind my keys and save them? I was using the generated class before abd things were working just fine, but I dind't find a way to rebind the keys and save them.
I tried following this and other similar tutorials on how to do it.
tutorial
At least the ones I checked out do rebinds without the Generated C# script.

I followed your advice @Jay and I went back to the generated C# script. Using the load and save functionality from the RebindUI sample package present in the Unity InputSystem Package, I added the Load and Save methods in the RebindActionUI script when OnComplete is called and it worked.
Had to also do some assembly definitions so that I could acess the RebindActionUI script outside of its assembly, since the standart Assembly-CSharp Unity creates for all your scripts cannot be added as an dependency for other assemblies.

Glad I could help :)
